# Make website not scrollable horizontally on mobile deives

Tags: html, css

I built a website and i am about to debug everything on mobile devices. I started looking at it on my iPhone SE. It seems that the website is still scrollable horizontally even if the body's `overflow-x` is set to `hidden` and i got following meta-tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Hmm, maybe adding max-width: 100% property to the body element?

Comment: This usually happens when some element is still overflowing the viewport on mobiles. Can you show us the example?